# Watin C# - Firefox instances

Tags: c#, watin

I've a class with 
class A :

```
      FireFox ff = new FireFox();
      ff.WaitForComplete();
```

class B
  Span targetTab = ff.Span(Find.ByText("System"));
         targetTab.Click();

i need to use  firefox instances ff.span in class B, if i do so we have to create an new object for firefox, and which inturns open another firefox browser. is there is anyway where i can attach both the "ff"instances together so that everything runs in same broser..

thanks,
Balaji S

Answer (score 0):

You can pass A classes ff instance to B class constructor and use it. Here is pseudo codeL

class A

```
FireFox ff = new FireFox();
ff.WaitForComplete();
B BClassInstance = new B(ff);//passing firefox instance
```

class B

```
//B class constructor
public B(FireFox useThisInstance)
{
  Span targetTab = useThisInstance.Span(Find.ByText("System")); //using instance created in A class
  targetTab.Click();
}
```